# How to use Google Drive to save media files for a Django app that is deployed in Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, google-drive-api

Is it possible to use Google Drive to save all the media files (image files which users will upload) from a Django app? This app will be deployed in Heroku (free). I am also aware of Amazon S3 but I want to avoid it as its not free after 12 months. I noticed that after deploying the app in Heroku, the static images are loading fine (using whitenoise) but those which are uploaded using `ImageField` from a model are not loading. I do not have any experience with Google APIs or even with Heroku for that matter and I could not find much information on if this integration is possible. If yes, it would be really great if I can get more details on how to go about it. I am currently using the latest version of Django (V3.0) along with Python 3.7.5 (64 bit).

***EDIT:***

Below is the changes I have made to try and use Google Drive to host media files with Heroku. I have used `django-googledrive-storage` as suggested below. But when I set DEBUG = False and run the code, I dont get any errors but I do not see any files getting uploaded or being accessed from google drive.

***Settings.py***

```
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Default Apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # User Apps
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'contacts.apps.ContactsConfig',
    'crispy_forms',  # For rendering forms
    'gdstorage'  # To host static and media files for Heroku
]

# Google drive storage settings
# I have added an environment variable with the same name and provided the full path
# of the JSON file where it is saved, like this - D:\secret_key.json
GOOGLE_DRIVE_STORAGE_JSON_KEY_FILE = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_DRIVE_STORAGE_JSON_KEY_FILE')
```

***models.py***

```
from gdstorage.storage import GoogleDriveStorage

# Define Google Drive Storage
gd_storage = GoogleDriveStorage()

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    .
    .
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users', default='default.png', blank=True, storage=gd_storage)
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 1):

Django uses the *storage backend* abstraction for static- and media-storage. See the two settings `STATICFILES_STORAGE` and `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`.

While most used cloud-providers are typically covered by [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/1.8/index.html), google drive is not supported.

But some googling gave me [this library here](https://django-googledrive-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me explore this library. I will surely come back and accept this answer if it works.. I am not a coder by profession. So kindly give me some time. :-)..

Comment: I followed all the steps as outlined in the documentation. Created a service account to get the secret key JSON file too. When I set DEBUG=False, everything runs fine. But I dont see any files getting uploaded or being accessed from Google drive. Not sure if I am missing something.. :-(

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you are using to upload the files with your Service Account?

Comment: @jescanellas, I just added the code pertaining to the `django-googledrive-storage` library. I am not sure if the JSON file path setting I have used in my environment variable is correct as I have specified the full path of the file as variable as I do not know how to pass JSON content itself.

Comment: I just checked that `os.environ.get('GOOGLE_DRIVE_STORAGE_JSON_KEY_FILE')` is returning only the path of the secret key json file. I think I should be passing the actual JSON content as a environment variable.